# Mysql Loop freeze Window in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, foreach, counter

I have mysql loop

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        int count = 1;

        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd;
            string qu = "INSERT INTO db(val1,val2,val3,val4,val5) VALUES("+value+")";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(qu, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            textBox1.Text = count.ToString();
            count++;
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

My goal is to show in textBox1 counter (loop has 18k+ rows), but when I start foreach loop my window is frozen and shows nothing until loop is end, and then show numbers in textbox, but I want to show current count number in real time.

Comment: Instead of blocking your UI thread, consider using a [ProgressBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbar?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Comment: Even when you have implemented one of the good suggestions below, I don't think you want to update your textbox 18000 times, you should make a threshold and only update every 100th time or whatever suits you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .NET you have couple of options, which i briefly will list below:

- creating and managing threads directly with `Thread` class and its API, which is "old-fashioned" way
- using async/await to enable asynchronous code (your libraries need to support async operations)
- if your libraries are not supporting async operations, you can always try wrapping it with `Task.Run`

You can find dozens of resources on each topic on the internet, so i am not going to go deeply into details.

In your case i guess there should be method [ExecuteNonQueryAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonqueryasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

And regarding UI - there is always good idea to show user sort of progress indication when we have operation that user waits for.

Comment: Note that if the OP is using MySql.Data, it's a longstanding known issue that the `Async` methods all execute synchronously: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111. To get the desired async behaviour, I would recommend switching to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ (disclaimer: lead author).

Answer (score -2):

You need one more thread to perform this action.

Comment: Oneliner answers are rarely useful. Either make this a comment, or add enough info that it can be considered an answer.

Comment: this needs more supporting information